# How to set Emacs to use standard LF line breaks, rather than CR

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

I am very new to Emacs, using Aquamacs on a Mac running OS 10.10. I'm creating and editing files that end up on a BSD system, so they need to conform to *nix standards. Apparently, the files I'm creating have carriage return line feeds, which my supervisor is understandably getting annoyed with having to strip out. I don't understand why this is the case, because my understanding is that the Mac hasn't used CR line breaks since they moved to OS 10. How can I fix this? Obviously, I'm not looking for a solution that has to be implemented for each new buffer I open, but rather a solution that will be the default for all new buffers.

Comment: AFAIK, by default Emacs never creates files that use CR as line breaks (under Windows, CRLF is used by default and LF is used by default everywhere else), so I think we need more details of your situation to understand why you end up with CR line breaks.

Comment: I'd be happy to provide any details needed, but I have no idea where to start with that.

Comment: For example: can you reproduce this with any file?  Can you reproduce this behavior with an empty `~/.emacs` file?  How exactly do you create your new files?